# C++ :: Notation with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this line of code:

```
model = ArticulatedModel::create(spec);
```

And I would like to grab the `AABox` from it using `AABox G3D::ArticulatedModel::Part::boxBounds` but I'm having trouble getting the C++ syntax to work.

How do I reference the boxBounds?

Comment: From what I can see, an articulated model consists of several parts, and each part consists of several meshes. Each mesh has an `AABox boxBounds`. You can't grab the `boxBounds` from an `ArticulatedModel` because it itself has no `AABox`; you'll have to calculate it manually from each of the meshes in each of the parts.

Comment: So theoretically I could examine the bounding box of every piece and grab the smallest and largest coordinate from all the boxes to get the global box, correct?

Comment: Probably. I can't be sure as I'm not familiar with the library you're using.

Comment: G3D, it's an openGL wrapper. This is the function: http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/courses/cs371/f10/G3D/manual/class_g3_d_1_1_articulated_model_1_1_part.html

Comment: @NathanTornquist the problem is that parts can have sub-parts and you'll have to recursively walk over all parts to get the global bounding box. Additionally all the bounding boxes are in object space and you need to transform them into global space (or at least parent space) if you want to compute the total bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

`create()` gives you an `ArticulatedModel`, but that doesn't have `boxBounds`. That attribute belongs to `ArticulatedModel::Part`, which is an entirely different class. To get a specific `Part` from the `ArticulatedModel` you need to use an `ID` or a name.